# Fetch SQL data?

Tags: sql-server-2008, powershell

I want to fetch data from a table when I run a PowerShell script. I have written the following script.
For some reason it is only displaying field counts and not the actual data.

My script:

```
Add-PSSnapin sqlserverprovidersnapin100
Add-PSSnapin sqlservercmdletsnapin100

$db =  get-content c:\users\riteshthakur\desktop\test.txt | select -index 0

$table = get-content c:\users\riteshthakur\desktop\test.txt | select -index 1

$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=.;Database=$db;Integrated Security=True"
$SqlConnection.Open()

$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = "select * from $table"
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection

$x = $SqlCmd.ExecuteReader()
Write-output $x

$SqlConnection.Close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you created the reader you need to actually [read the data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms199426%28v=sql.120%29.aspx):

```
$x = $SqlCmd.ExecuteReader()
while ($x.Read()) {
  $x.GetValue(0)
  $x.GetValue(1)
  ...
}
$x.Close()
```

Or you could use an [`SQLDataAdapter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of a reader:

```
$SqlCmd = $SqlConnection.CreateCommand()
$SqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM $table"
$SqlAdapter = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $SqlCmd
$tbl = New-Object Data.DataTable
$SqlAdapter.Fill($tbl)
$tbl | Format-Table -AutoSize
```